# How do I detect and remove Python packages installed via pip?

Tags: python, package-management, pip

I have accidently installed Python packages to my system using `pip` instead of `apt-get`. I did this in two ways:

- using an older version of virtualenv, I forgot to append `--no-site-packages` when creating the virtualenv - after that when I called `pip install`, the Python packages where installed to the system rather than the virtualenv
- in a correctly setup virtualenv, I typed `sudo pip install somepackage` - the sudo installed to the system rather than the virtualenv

I happened to notice this because I typed `pip freeze` outside a virtualenv, and spotted some Python packages listed that shouldn't be there. So now my question is:

- how do I identify all Python packages that have been erroneously installed on the system (that is, Python packages that appear in the `pip freeze` list, but were not installed with `apt-get`)?
- how do I remove them?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Ubuntu Oneiric (and I expect newer versions too) install pip packages to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`, and `apt` packages to `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`. So just check the former directory and `sudo pip uninstall` every package you find there.

Comment: I went brutal and issued `sudo rm -r /usr/local/lib/python2.7`. So far so good.

Comment: @Apteryx, i did the same with `/usr/local/lib/python3.5`, and after a while an upgrade of `update-notifier-common` package failed because of missing Python 3 `six` package.  I ended up installing `six` with `sudo -H pip3 install six`.

Comment: @Apteryx god damn you man! I did the same and now my whole system is all fucked up! because almost everything in ubuntu relies on python!

Comment: I have noticed that i now have a bunch of broken executables in `/usr/local/bin/` (a while ago i just removed `/usr/local/lib/python3.5` and switched to [conda](https://conda.io/docs/)).

Answer (score 33):

Pip currently ignores uninstall commands that try to uninstall something owned by the OS. It doesn't error out, like it does with a missing package. So, now you can uninstall with the following process:

```
pip freeze > dump.txt
```

Edit the dumped file to remove any `-e` "editable install" lines, everything after the `==` sign (`%s;==.*;;g` in vim), swap the new lines for spaces (`%s;\n; ;g` in vim). Then you can uninstall all un-owned packages with

```
cat dump.txt | xargs sudo pip uninstall -y
```

I had to do this procedure twice, because a few packages were installed in `~/.local/lib` too.

---

A one-liner to accomplish this:

```sh
pip freeze | grep -vP '^(?:#|-e\s)' | sed 's;==.*;;g' | xargs -r sudo pip uninstall -y
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to me

Comment: Should anyone want a vimless one-liner: `sudo pip uninstall -y $(pip freeze | sed 's;==.*;;g' | tr '\n' ' ')`

Comment: Careful! This depends on whether your OS ships a special version of `pip`. On archlinux `pip` happily uninstalls system packages. On the other hand, `pip` on debian jessie complains and errors: `Not uninstalling virtualenv at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, owned by OS`

Comment: do you need the sudo?  -- this should definitely be the accepted answer

Comment: Any guesses what it means if I get "Found existing installation: Routes 2.4.1
Not uninstalling routes at /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages, outside environment /usr
Can't uninstall 'Routes'. No files were found to uninstall.
"  (for every installed package) (on Ubuntu focal)

Comment: This solution is awesome, but runs into the issue of aborting on `distutils` installed projects on Ubuntu

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK `sudo pip install` will install on `/usr/local/lib/pythonVERSION/dist-packages`. You need to run `sudo pip uninstall` to uninstall packages system wide. It seems that `pip freeze` looks for package metadata and will list anything installed i.e. both from pip as well as apt-get outside of virtualenvs. There is `-l` option inside virtual environment to list packages only applicable to that virtual environment but it seems to be default case as well inside virtual environment. I think you can just delete related packages on `/usr/local/lib/pythonVERSION/dist-packages` as well but not very convenient method I guess.

Answer (score 6):

To removing a package installed via pip, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
pip uninstall < package-name >
```

To search for packages

```
pip search <package you want to search for>
```

To determine which Python packages were installed by pip, by the `freeze` command, which will give you a list of installed packages and their versions.  I would suggest removing all instances, and re-installing using the `sudo apt-get` command

```
sudo apt-get install python3
```

Comment: how do I determine which Python packages were installed by pip, and which by apt-get? can I still `pip uninstall` if I used `sudo pip install` in the first place?

Comment: @d3vid `pip freeze` only shows packages it installed (AFAICS).

Comment: @oli pip freeze, in precise at least, also lists packages installed by apt, as other answers here describe.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to clean up disk space from Python packages safely. While this is a complete clean out of packages, I needed to move Python versions  as well so I did not need old packages.  I used the following to get all my package names, skip the first 2 lines and grab the first column, and uninstall without user interaction:

```
pip list | awk 'NR>2 {print $1}' | xargs -I {} pip uninstall -y {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following to uninstall all the pip packages from my virtual environment:

```bsh
pip list | tail -n+3 | grep -ve '^#\|^wheel\|^pip\|^setuptools ' | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

I still keep `wheel`, `pip` and `setuptools`.

Also, `pip list` is preferable over `pip freeze` in my case since `pip list` lists the packages installed with `-e` with just their names.

Answer (score -2):

This has something to do with Homebrew. I had no issues with pyodbc on my Mac Air until I installed Homebrew and used it for a few things. I found [this thread on github](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/101) that ends in a solution that worked for me.

"If you have Homebrew, just install the ODBC headers:

```
$ brew install unixodbc
```

and run "pip install pyodbc" again."

This 100% solved the problem for me and only took a moment. Give it a shot.

Comment: maybe you need to post this at Ask Different? https://apple.stackexchange.com