# How to "reset" python installation in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, python, python3

after installing several packages with the package manager, some others using eggs, some others using pip, for 2 versions of python, with some packages that in the meantime changed name (iPython --> Jupyter).. briefly, my python installation is in a mess state!

How can I reset both system and local python systems to default ubuntu 14.04 ?

Comment: I already asked almost the same question once, but unfortunately did not really get any answer: http://askubuntu.com/q/675142/367990

Answer (score 1):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248073/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-remove-all-packages-installed-by-pip#11250821) you can remove packages installed by pip with this command:

```
pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y
```