# pylint3 and pip3 broken

Tags: apt, python, python3

I have tried `sudo apt remove --purge` on various packages. I get the same when I reinstall.

I have also tried reinstall using aptitude. This does not work.

My current workaround is to run pylint3 as root, which works, but is bad practice.

pip3

```
    $ pip3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 33, in vendored
    __import__(vendored_name, globals(), locals(), level=0)
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.pkg_resources'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip3", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    from pip.exceptions import InstallationError, CommandError, PipError
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/exceptions.py", line 6, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.six import iteritems
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 75, in <module>
    vendored("pkg_resources")
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 36, in vendored
    __import__(modulename, globals(), locals(), level=0)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 634, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 956, in subscribe
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in <lambda>
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2515, in activate
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2097, in declare_namespace
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2047, in _handle_ns
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/pkg_resources-0.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2066, in _rebuild_mod_path
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

pylint3

```
$ pylint3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pylint3", line 3, in <module>
    run_pylint()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pylint/__init__.py", line 22, in run_pylint
    from pylint.lint import Run
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pylint/lint.py", line 44, in <module>
    import astroid
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/astroid/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from astroid.nodes import *
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/astroid/nodes.py", line 54, in <module>
    from astroid.scoped_nodes import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/astroid/scoped_nodes.py", line 35, in <module>
    from astroid import manager
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/astroid/manager.py", line 29, in <module>
    from astroid import modutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/astroid/modutils.py", line 40, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2927, in <module>
    @_call_aside
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2913, in _call_aside
    f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in _initialize_master_working_set
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 956, in subscribe
    callback(dist)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2952, in <lambda>
    add_activation_listener(lambda dist: dist.activate())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2515, in activate
    declare_namespace(pkg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2097, in declare_namespace
    _handle_ns(packageName, path_item)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2047, in _handle_ns
    _rebuild_mod_path(path, packageName, module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2066, in _rebuild_mod_path
    orig_path.sort(key=position_in_sys_path)
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'
```

**update**
This fixed it.
`sudo apt remove --purge python3-setuptools`
I would love to understand how.

**update update**
I re-installed dependencies that I need. Then the problem cam back.

@Kenavera I am at the newest python3-tools from the repo (according to synaptic python3-tools 20.7.0-1, which seems quite old).

running python3 as me, as pylint3 at root is working. I still would like a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Clean up python installation**
[Restore Python installation to default plus apt package dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/675142/restore-python-installation-to-default-plus-apt-package-dependencies)

list all things manually installed via apt:

`comm -23 <(apt-mark showmanual | sort -u) <(gzip -dc /var/log/installer/initial-status.gz | sed -n 's/^Package: //p' | sort -u)`

remove pylint3 and all python3-*. For me this was:

`sudo apt remove pylint3 python3-googleapi python3-lxml python3-matplotlib python3-numpy python3-pip python3-pyocr python3-scipy python3-tk python-lxml python-numpy python-pip python-setuptools`

`sudo apt autoremove`

list things installed via pip `ls -ltd /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/*`

remove them

```
pip3 uninstall setuptools
pip3 uninstall pydicom
pip3 uninstall docx
```

lastly pip itself

`pip3 uninstall pip`

delete everything installed for the user by deleting all from here

'$HOME/.local/lib/python*'

**Reinstall**

`sudo apt install python3-pip pylint3 python3-venv`

**Set up virtual environment**

I have a project called plan-report. in that directory (not as root)

```
python3 -m venv plan-report-env
chmod +x ./plan-report-env/bin/activate

# this line needs repeating each time a terminal is opened
./plan-report-env/bin/activate
```

reinstall python packages in the virtual environment. eg

```
pip install numpy
```

Note that it was python3 that created the venv, so now you just say `pip`, not `pip3`. seems ok to upgrade pip within the venv too.

`pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get upgrade python-setuptools` did the trick for me. Hope this helps you too.

Comment: Nice too see you have solved it. 
I found my source after your follow up question in: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4216

There it is stated that: 
`... the problem arose when Setuptools 31 introduced support for setup.py develop on namespace packages, which required the expansion of -nspkg.pth files. This change essentially meant that older versions of pkg_resources didn't support this new format and would choke.
` and this seems to be also applicable to your command.