# checkbox software problem in ubuntu 16

Tags: python, python3, checkbox

I have an issue with checkbox software on ubuntu 16.

[image: Checkbox System Testing Software]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I think this is because I have many versions of python. More specific, I have python3 and python3.5, which I think causes the problem, because as shown in the image it needs "requests" module which is available in my system in python3.5 and not python3.

So how can I solve the problem?

**Update:**

As shown in the second image there is one python file "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/plainbox/impl/transport.py" which is trying to find the "requests" module in the same path "/usr/lib/python3/" but the "requests" folder is in "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages" i.e. "/usr/local/lib" not "/usr/lib" (user library rather than system one). I ended up editing "transport.py"  and adding

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages")
```

before

```
 import request
```

and it worked.

**The question is:** how to tell "Checkbox" to automatically detect the packages in "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages" because it is not convenient to edit source files and point to other the paths (by the way every installed package on my system is stored in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/ so why "Checkbox" is pointing to "/usr/lib/python3").

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this version of 'requests' does not link with your Python. You could try to install it for python3.5 by: `pip3 install --upgrade --force-reinstall requests`.
Please use virtual env instead of many copies of Python in the same operating system.

Please read for future:

[Virtual Environments and Packages | Python 3.6.5rc1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)

**Edited:**
Check this out:

[How do I detect and remove Python packages installed via pip? | Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/173323/how-do-i-detect-and-remove-python-packages-installed-via-pip/259747#259747)

Comment: This command does not help. Please see the update above.

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: As what I understood: pip packages to /usr/local/lib/python... , and apt packages to /usr/lib/python...  but in my case both install to  /usr/local/lib/python3.5/... and the weird thing is that I didn't install python3 and python3.5 all what I did during the installation is e.g. sudo apt-get install python3-... or sudo pip3 install ... so why am I having these two versions python3 and python3.5

Comment: Just check your screenshot from above, python3 is a link to python3.5. It is working as the alias.

Comment: That is right, but I am taking about python3 as packages (not the executable) because I have packages in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/  and in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/. The later has the newly installed packages. Taking into consideration that I used commands like: sudo apt-get install python3-... or sudo pip3 install ... 
so why am I having python3 and python3.5 folders OR packages (I think there should be only one them)?